# Need to add time delay between .each elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I need help inserting something llike a delay between executing that "code()".For example I want it to execute one after another every 4 seconds.So like first one executes, that after 4 seconds the code executes again and so on for each of the elements with given class.

Im also using .this in that "code()" so I need it to stay there because for example im getting the id of every given class and using that.

```
var myFunction = function(){

        $(".someClass").each( function(){

            if( this.style.opacity != "0.5" ){


                code();


            }

        });
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried to use setInterval(code,4000)

Comment: @carton it will just do all of the each after 4 seconds, each is not async.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: So you have to use setTimeout look at answer below

Comment: he is giving different time for each run of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use `each` loop index to delay it using timeouts:

```
var myFunction = function() {
  $(".someClass").each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (this.style.opacity != "0.5") {
        code();
      }
    }.bind(this), i * 4000); // bind relevant context
  });
};
```

Other version, using `filter()`:

```
var myFunction = function() {
  $(".someClass").filter(function(){
    return this.style.opacity != "0.5";
  }).each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(code.bind(this), i * 4000);
  });
};
```

Comment: The first version of the code works great, but what if i want it to check first for each element the opacity and only if that is true then execute the code.

Because now for example if first two are false and third is true it waits 8 seconds for each before coming to third and executing the code.

Comment: The second one using filter() should work as you expect it

Comment: Now it does first check for opacity for all elements of that class but in that second code it executes that "code()" even faster than 4 seconds and if there is one element that is true it executes the code on it multiple times...it doesnt go to the next one if there is more...

Comment: @Tyrone It works as expected here: https://jsfiddle.net/mbehkrpx/  So you should provide jsFiddle replicating your issue. Maybe your issue has something to do with code in `code()`?! Are you changing `opacity` of element in this callback method?

Comment: @Tyrone And as a side note, you should check opacity using `$(this).css('opacity') != 0.5` instead of `this.style.opacity != "0.5"`. But the best would be to handle opacity in CSS using a class and check if element has this class

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mbehkrpx/6/ Im guessing its something obvious but idk what is wrong. The openT function is the "code()" that i need to use btw and it need to get a llink as a parameter everytime, and that is "https://www.something.com/something/" + this.id.split("-")[2]

Comment: @Tyrone The problem is how do you call timeout callback. You call the method and so timeout uses what function return, here `undefined` (your method return nothing). The easiest one is to wrap it inside anonymous function: `setTimeout( function(){openT( "http://www.websitetest.com/" + this.id )}.bind(this), i * 4000);`. But comes an other issue, in your code you are trying to open a popup but most moder browsers block it automatically if it doesn't follow any user interaction

Comment: Im using it on only one site where i enabled it so popups are not the problem

Comment: @Tyrone So try it on your site. As a side note, you could use: `setTimeout( openT.bind(this), i * 4000, "http://www.websitetest.com/" + this.id);`

Comment: Yes wrapping it worked nicely, and the other way also works, thanks a lot for explaining all this man :)